# How to best use Numpy/Scipy to find optimal common coefficients for a set different linear equations?

Tags: numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, scipy-optimize

I have n (around 5 million) sets of specific (k,m,v,z)* parameters that describe some linear relationships. I want to find the optimal positive a,b and c coefficients that minimize the addition of their absolute values as shown below:

[image]

I know beforehand the range for each a, b and c and so, I could use it to make things a bit faster. However, I do not know how to properly implement this problem to best take advantage of Numpy (or Scipy/etc).

I was thinking of iteratively making checks using different a, b and c coefficients (based on a step) and in the end keeping the combination that would provide the minimum sum. But properly implementing this in Numpy is another thing.

*
(k,m,v are either 0 or positive and are in fact k,m,v,i,j,p)
(z can be negative too)

Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Either I am missing something, or `a == b == c == 0` is optimal. So, a positive solution for `(a,b,c)` does not exist in general. You can verify this explicitly by posing the minimization problem as a quantile regression of `0` on `(k, m, v)` with the quantile set to `0.5`.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg

x = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
a, b, c = QuantReg(np.zeros(x.shape[0]), x).fit(0.5).params

assert np.allclose([a, b, c], 0)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I oversimplified. I changed the description adding the Z values which are residuals (having no coefficients attached to them) and can be either positive or negative.

Comment: In this case, `QuantReg(residuals, x).fit(0.5).params` should work, where `x=(k,m,c)`. There may be faster methods that specialize to the least absolute differences regression, which sounds like what you want.